# store result of stored procedure which returns multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have one stored `dbo.usp_GetCustInfo '1','Some Parameter'` which return two tables

As

Table 1

```
DocID    DocName
```

Table 2

```
CustID     CustName
```

I want to store this into temp table. i can use any of the statement `Insert into` or `Select * Into`

As pointed in this answer [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure) **it works only if return one table**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for OUTPUT parameters within your stored procedure.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

I don't know of any possibility to handle plural result-sets within T-SQL, as far as i know it's strictly designed to handle only singular results - and since you can't edit the Stored Procedure itself, you should work with the result within the language you are using to process the information from SQL. I can provide an example for ColdFusion, i guess there are similar approaches possible for most other languages.

```
<!--- This calls the procedure --->
<cfstoredproc procedure="usp_GetCustInfo" datasource="your_ds">
  <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="1" />
  <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="Some Parameter" />
  <cfprocresult name="local.table_1" resultset=1 />
  <cfprocresult name="local.table_2" resultset=2 />
</cfstoredproc>

<cfdump var=#local.table_1# title="Result Table 1">
<cfdump var=#local.table_2# title="Result Table 2">
```

Comment: Everyone can link to docs. Try to provide a minimal example to make your anser more informative.

Comment: @Weision i can not change existing stored procedure structure !

Comment: @SagarDumbre Which language are you using to communicate with SQL Server? In some (i guess actually in most) languages it's possible to handle multiple results from a query. I can provide an example for ColdFusion, will add it to my post